# Javascript inheritance : parent property not enabled

Tags: javascript

Here is my code to achieve my inheritance:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>JavaScript Patterns</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        /* Title: Classical Pattern #5 - A Temporary Constructor (a pattern that should be generally avoided)
         Description: first borrow the constructor and then also set the child's prototype to point to a new instance of the constructor
         */


        /* Basic */
        /*function inherit(C, P) {
         var F = function () {};
         F.prototype = P.prototype;
         C.prototype = new F();
         }*/


        /* Storing the Superclass */
        /*function inherit(C, P) {
         var F = function () {};
         F.prototype = P.prototype;
         C.prototype = new F();
         C.uber = P.prototype;
         }*/


        /* Resetting the Constructor Pointer */
        /*function inherit(C, P) {
         var F = function () {};
         F.prototype = P.prototype;
         C.prototype = new F();
         C.uber = P.prototype;
         C.prototype.constructor = C;
         }*/


        /* in closure */
        var inherit = (function () {
            var F = function () {
            };
            return function (C, P) {
                F.prototype = P.prototype;
                C.prototype = new F();
                C.uber = P.prototype;
                C.prototype.constructor = C;
            }
        }());


        function Parent(name) {
            this.nameParent = name || 'Adam';
            this.parentName = "parent";//this.nameParent;
        }


        // adding functionality to the prototype
        Parent.prototype.say = function () {
            return this.nameParent;
        };



        // child constructor
        function Child(nameChild) {
            console.log("parentprop:" + this.parentName);
        }

        inherit(Child, Parent);


        var kid = new Child();
        console.log(kid.name); // undefined
        console.log(typeof kid.say); // function
        kid.nameParent = 'Patrick';
        console.log(kid.parentName);
        console.log(kid.say()); // Patrick
        console.log(kid.constructor.nameParent); // Child
        console.log(kid.constructor === Parent); // false




        // reference
        // http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596806767.do
    </script>
</body>
```

I need the Child console.log to display "parent" from the parent class inherited, but for now, it only displays undefined.

I don't know why it doesn't inherit from parent property.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you never call the function `Parent`, which is what's setting the property. If you look closely at your `inherit` function, you're using the `prototype` property of `P` but you're never calling `P` — which is a good thing; it's `Child` who should call `P`:

```
function Child(nameChild) {
    Parent.call(this);
    console.log("parentprop:" + this.parentName);
}
```

Obviously, this has the disadvantage that you have to list `Parent` in more than one place — both in your call to `inherit`, and in `Child`. You could mitigate that by setting the parent constructor on the child function in `inherit`:

```
var inherit = (function () {
    var F = function () {
    };
    return function (C, P) {
        F.prototype = P.prototype;
        C.parent = P;          // <==== The new bit
        C.prototype = new F();
        C.uber = P.prototype;
        C.prototype.constructor = C;
    }
}());
```

...so then `Child` becomes:

```
function Child(nameChild) {
    Child.parent.call(this);
    console.log("parentprop:" + this.parentName);
}
```

If you're interested in doing hierarchies thoroughly (with support for calling "super" methods and such), you might want to look at my [`Lineage` toolkit](http://code.google.com/p/lineagejs). It's a small toolkit that automates a lot of this stuff, but if you want to learni how this stuff works, the source might make for interesting reading. There's also a [wiki page](http://code.google.com/p/lineagejs/wiki/ComparisonWithPlainJavaScript) there showing multi-layer, fully-functional inheritance *without* using `Lineage` (as a means of comparing it with using `Lineage`).

Comment: Thanks that's working, but C.uber must be changed to C.parent.prototype = P.prototype; no?

Comment: I will investigate in Lineage too.

Comment: uber is intended to be as super or parent accessor.

Comment: @Alphapage: *"uber is intended to be as super or parent accessor."* If so, just set `uber = P;` and if you ever need parent *prototype* rather than the parent constructor, use `C.uber.prototype`. Or just have both, for brevity, although there's a *slight* difference in that if you always refer back to `P.prototype`, and someone replaces (instead of augmenting) `P.prototype`, you'll always get that updated version. Of course, it won't match the prototype backing the instance anymore if someone does that...